# How is the date account balance calculated in banking software?

Tags: finance, software-design, banking

How is the account balance calculated for a particular date for a customer right from date of opening account till today.

Comment: The basic naive idea is just to take the initial balance when the account was opened and then add or subtract the value of any transaction that has occurred until the current day or the date in question.

Comment: To follow up on @Striezel's comment, most banks create monthly statements, so each account has a dated balance at least once a month, if not more often.  It's not difficult to keep every calculated balance for every account for the last seven years.